# How to compare element in list with the next element and separate if same?

Tags: python, list

I have a string, that contains random letters and numbers, but if there are two letters or numbers that are same and next to each other, then you have to separate them with `"/"`. So the input string is `"uBBjkko"`, and the result should be `"uB/Bjk/ko"`.

Right now I have converted my string to list so I could compare every element to the the next:

```py
mylist ['u', 'B', 'B', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'o']
for i in range(len(mylist)):
        if mylist[i] == mylist[i + 1]:
            mylist.insert(i + 1, "/")
print("".join(mylist))
```

but the code doesn't work if the list gets too long and if the list ends with two same letters or number such as

```py
['u', 'B', 'B', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'o', '2', '2']
```

then the output will be `"uB/Bjk/ko22"` but it needs to be `"uB/Bjk/ko2/2"`.

Comment: First of all you have a syntax error there: `for i in range(len(mylist)):` you missed the last bracket ;)

Comment: @LeoE oh yes, thank you, didnt notice that, but sadly it doesnt fix my problem :(

Comment: And all you are missing is a +1, it should be `for i in range(len(mylist)+1):` then it works ;)

Comment: @LeoE oh thank you, it fixed a little bit, but if the string is too long, then its not working and also if the string ends with two same letters :/

Comment: Yes, the problem is, that you insert your placeholder while iterating, therefore changing the length of the list. So after an insertion it follows, that the next time you check "/" and the next letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said in the comment the problem is, that you insert while iterating. By iterating the other way around from end to begin you fix it. This way your iteration is not affected by the insertion:

```
mylist = ['u', 'B', 'B', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'o', '2', '2']
for i in range(len(mylist)-1, 0, -1): # This goes from len(mylist)-1 to 0 in -1 steps
    if mylist[i] == mylist[i-1]:
        mylist.insert(i, '/')
print("".join(mylist))
```

Comment: That is clever use of range

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solves your issue, so others know, that it works ;) And your welcome ;)

Comment: You can use `mylist[:1:-1]` in place of `range(len(mylist)-1, 0, -1)`

Comment: @shahkalpesh to do what? Since I'm not iterating over the list it doesn't help

Comment: Oh, I see that you are using index based iteration than using a for each character kind of an iteration. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

mylist = ['u', 'B', 'B', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'o', '2', '2']
print("".join([a + ('/' if a == b else '') for a,b in zip_longest(mylist, mylist[1:], fillvalue='')]))
```

Though it may be a bit much, you can learn about `itertools` module. `zip` function or `zip_longest` function in this case and list comprehension too.